# Better understanding of OAuth 1.0

Tags: authentication, encryption, oauth

I want to understand the process behind OAuth 1.0.

Given:

- Oauth_token
- Oauth_consumer_key
- The calling URL

How is "Oauth_nonce" and "Oauth_signature" generated in HMAC-SHA1?

Do I need other information?

Comment: Looks like your question relates to the protocol and not a specific programming issue. I've voted to close as "off topic", but you may wish to repost at http://crypto.stackexchange.com. I would also recommend you read the relevant specs before you post another question otherwise you'll receive down-votes for a lack of research.

Comment: +1 what Duncan said. Check out the official docs: `tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849`